# Creating exe from py which passes argument by default on execution?

Tags: python, arguments, cross-compiling, pyinstaller, py2exe

If we assume this is the test.py code:

```
import sys
 
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
print "Hello World!"
```

By using tools like [auto-py-to-exe](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) or [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PassingOptionsToPy2Exe) or ..., How can we make an exe which passes an specific argument on execution by default ? For example: By using a tool we make an test.exe from the test.py and by executing the test.exe it will use foobar as arg, The output of the test.exe execution is:

```
foobar
Hello World!
```

I have already tested auto-py-to-exe and pyinstaller but there is not such an option in both. I should mention that i am more interested in using [any] tools and not just modifying the python source. Because the modifying might be a hard task in bigger sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using pythons ArgumentParser (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) and just set a `default=` value for your argument.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("argument", default="foobar")
args = parser.parse_args()

print arg
print "Hello World!"
```

You can also restructure your called python script to implement a "main" method with the arguments you need:

```
def main(argument):
    print argument
    print "Hello World!"
```

For your specific executables just create separate wrapper-scripts:

foobar.py

```
from test import main
test("foobar")
```

anotherfoobar.py

```
from test import main
test("anotherfoobar")
```

Now you can use pyinstaller to create executables of foobar.py and anotherfoobar.py separatly.

Comment: Thank you for the resource and examples, Seems like a working solution specially in such simple codes , But i am looking for a tool-side solution, Not modifying the py file (i will mention this in the question), Because the source code that im facing it is 6000 lines of code and hard to modify.